# how to use the wifi of WP7 to connect to another wifi to WP7 by transferet of them as simple msg

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I want to know how to use the wifi of WP7 to connect to another wifi to WP7 by transferet of them as simple msg ("hello").
 thank you

Answer (score 2):

So you want to establish a direct connection between two wp7 devices through wi-fi, and you want to send messages between them? Unfortunately you can't do this on this platform, you can't bind a socket to listen incoming connections. Maybe in the next version of Windows Phone.

The only way to do this is to use a server in the middle which both devices connect to.

Comment: ok thanks and is that I can send a message to a pc from a windows phone is using the wifi, ie the windows to connect to pc with wifi and he sent a message.
Thanks againe